# How to prevent a parameter from getting injected in controller methods in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, parameters, laravel-routing

I am creating a multilingual website in Laravel. I need urls to be like that:

```
https://website.com/en/admin/user/1
https://website.com/ar/admin/user/1
```

so my route file looks like that:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => '{locale}'], function(){
Route::middleware("locale")->group(function () {

Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin', 'as' => "admin.", "namespace" => "Admin"],function(){

    Route::get('login', 'LoginController@index')->name("signin")->middleware("Guest");
    Route::post('login', 'LoginController@login')->name('login')->middleware("Guest");

    Route::group(["middleware" => "Admin"], function (){

        Route::get('/', ["as" => "dashboard", "uses" =>'DashboardController@index']);
        Route::get('logout', 'LoginController@logout')->name('logout');
        Route::resource('users', 'UsersController');

    });

});

});
});
```

My middleware "locale":

```
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{

    URL::defaults(['locale' => $request->segment(1)]);
    if(in_array($request->segment(1), config('app.locales')))
    {
        app()->setLocale($request->segment(1));
    }
    return $next($request);

}
```

Now the problem is that when I try to call a use a route with parameters I have to add the locale as a first parameter. For example:
this is a method in UsersController:

```
    public function destroy($locale, $id)
{
    //Any Code

}
```

I have to add $locale as a parameter to the method to be able to use the other parameters or the $id will have the value of the $locale which is "en", "ar" instead of the user id. So is there any way I can avoid that so my method will look like:

```
    public function destroy($id)
{
    //Any Code
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can build your routes for example like this:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => app()->getLocale()], function(){
```

so you will get rid of locale route parameter.

Comment: Yes, I can do that, but now users won't be able to change languages by changing the URL.

Comment: Well, it depends how you allow to change languages, you can create loop looping over all languages or if you want to allow to change language only for mainpage you can create some extra routes just to handle mainpage langauges change